# How to check the latest possible state number of Geth

Tags: go-ethereum

Good day for everyone.

We are using geth with fast synch for own node on AWS t2.large with
ssd volume.
And it synching continuously, having 100 blocks behind current
and states growing.
I know this is old question and geth will not be in synch untill all
states loaded.
For now eth.syncing outputs:

```
{
 currentBlock: 12476357,
 highestBlock: 12476443,
 knownStates: 808119241,
 pulledStates: 808061533,
 startingBlock: 12451471
}
```

And we would like to know what time it needs to be in synch.
Does anybody know what is approximate number of Ethereum states for
nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the latest block information in a blockchain explorer. For example, [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/).

Comment: Thank you for response, Mikko Ohtamaa. I can achieve block number, but what about state using in geth?

Comment: For the state information, if you cannot find it from EtherScan, I recommend getting a hosted node like QuickNode or Infura and getting it from there. Though not 100% sure if they expose this API.

Comment: This is great idea. But using infura node, `w3.eth.syncing` returns `False`.

Comment: I'm guessing, for that we can use subscription. For Infura, using wscat utilite it will looks like `wscat -c wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID \ {"jsonrpc":"2.0", "id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["syncing"]}`

Comment: Waiting for a little, we got: `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_subscription","params":{"subscription":"0x45b78d57e66f355e79ab793b57ab91e0","result":{"syncing":true,"status":{"StartingBlock":12477750,"CurrentBlock":12477801,"HighestBlock":12477751,"PulledStates":684651941,"KnownStates":684651941}}}}` This is different with our states, since we have: 810036548

Comment: We are using geth-linux-amd64-1.10.2-97d11b01 with default parameters, achieved via :  `./geth-linux-amd64-1.10.2-97d11b01/geth --networkid 1 --rpcport 8555 dumpconfig > config_init.toml`

Comment: Also, we noticed, infura states are not changing at all.

Comment: Hello. Eventually we got all states and now have `{
  currentBlock: 12534617,
  highestBlock: 12534627,
  knownStates: 901757157,
  pulledStates: 901757157,
  startingBlock: 12534605
}`  This is for geth instance: Geth/v1.10.3-stable-991384a7/linux-amd64/go1.16.3